# How can I bring back the "Recent" folder in Nautilus side bar?

Tags: 22.04, nautilus

After an updated to Ubuntu 22.04.2, skipping over a few versions, the "Recent" folder in the side bar of my Nautilus has disappeared. The "Recent" folder is still there and works as expected in the file chooser, but not in Nautilus:

[image: Place where I expected the "Recent" folder.]

I tried removing all configuration files with paths containing "nautilus" in my home directory and removed my ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini, nothing helped. Looking at recently posted screenshots of Nautilus, it supposedly still should be there.

I have my "File History" turned on:

[image]

The location "recent:///" or "recent://", recommended [here](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/enabledisable-recent-option-nautilus-sidebar-ubuntu-16-04/) for Ubuntu 16.04, does not appear to exist any more.

What can I do to restore the Recent folder? Is there some hidden configuration file that controls its appearance?

Comment: have you tried recycling the option `Show Sidebar` in Nautilus? Open `Files` select the hamburger menu check and uncheck `Show Sidebar`

Comment: What do you mean by "updated to Ubuntu 22.04.2, skipping over a few versions,":  did you reinstall fresh or did you do subsequent upgrades. One can only upgrade from one version to the next, or from one LTS to the next.

Comment: @graham: Yes, "Show Sidebar" is on.

Comment: @vanadium: I upgraded from one LTS to the next. But the was a some problem, so I had to do a "apt --fix-broken install" to get it over the line. All else works nicely. Currently, I am running nautilus 42.6 and GNOME 42.5. I might also have accidentally removed the "Recent" entry from the sidebar if this is possible at all.

Comment: that's not what I asked - I asked if you had recycled it - ie turn it off then back on again.

Comment: @graham: sorry, yes, I tried turning sidebar on and off as well. The sidebar comes back -- no, change, unfortunately.